# Combine 2 arrays and fill with 0 if they are not duplicates

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have two arrays with datetimes. I want to display the values in the x-axis of a chart.

I need a function that combine the arrays in one and add a '0' where aren't duplicates.

```js
array 1 = [2016-01-20,2016-01-21,2016-01-24]
array 2 = [2016-01-21]

final array = [0, 2016-01-21, 0]
```

Is there any quick way to this?

thank you very much

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript-and-de-duplicate-items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with [`map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and  [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```js
var array1 = ['2016-01-20', '2016-01-21', '2016-01-24']
var array2 = ['2016-01-21']

var final = array1.map(function(e) {
  return (array2.indexOf(e) == -1) ? e = 0 : e;
});

console.log(final)
```

Answer (score 1):

Just loop through first array and check if value is in second array.

```
foreach ($array1 as &$date) {
    if (!in_array($date, $array2)) {
        $date = 0;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is PHP, and the tags say javascript